# How to get the parent objects class name from an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord

Is it possible to return the parent object of a given attribute?

## Example

```
  a = User.birthdate
  a.parent_object ... should return the user record that is the parent of the birthdate attribute
```

A better example?

## Helper

```
 def item_grade(subject, obj)
     obj.scale.grades.find(subject.grade_id).name # would return something like "Pass", "Fail", "Good Job"
 end
```

## In the view

```
 item_grade(@course.subject, @course)
```

This approach requires two options to be passed to the helper.  It seems I should be able to pass @course.subject and then get the parent object from that

## Helper

```
 def item_grade(subject)
     a = subject.parent_object.scale
     a.grades.find(subject.grade_id).name
 end
```

## View

```
 item_grade(@course.subject)
```

Comment: Nope, not possible. Attribute values are plain primitives (strings, dates, numbers, etc). They have no concept of a "parent".

Comment: I suppose you could override all the accessor methods to return little `value,parent` objects that forwarded most method calls to `value` via some `method_missing` hackery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This approach requires two options to be passed to the helper.

You can remove some duplication by doing this, for example.

```
 def item_grade(obj, property)
     obj.scale.grades.find(obj.send(property).grade_id).name
 end

 item_grade(@course, :subject)
```

Now you don't have to repeat `@course` in the call.

Having to pass two parameters is much less harmful than any sort of hackery you can come up with (thanks @muistooshort). There's no built-in way to do this.